# Nuxt 3 with navigateTo ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a pagination that is tied to the address bar of the format `/catalog/[slug]?page=1`. I can freely navigate through the catalog pages by writing the page number `?page=1` in the address bar. I'm tracking `page` and making a request to the server.

The problem is that after the page is reloaded, `watch` does not have time to do the work and the data does not arrive. Then I just run the prepare() function and get the error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` from `NavigateTo`.

What could be the problem? I'm just replacing the path.

I tried it but it didn't help

```
watch(currentPage, () => {
prepare()},{immediate:true})
```

the problem is `NavigateTo`

```js
// check query on create
const currentPage = useState<number>(() => parseInt(query.page))
// watch when page change
watch(currentPage, () => {
    prepare()

})
//change route and call api
const prepare =async (): Promise<void> => {
   await navigateTo({
        path: path,
        query: {
            page: currentPage.value,

        }
    }, {
        redirectCode: 301,
        replace: true
    })
//call api
    if (typeItem() && currentPage.value) {
        loadMore(typeItem(), currentPage.value)

    }
}
 prepare()
```

[image]

Comment: You are watching the prepare function, which is doing an infinite loop of navigating to the same page URL. Please show your file structure and I will write a solution that will work for you!

Comment: Based on your file structure, you are navigating index.vue and not your [id] route. Is that your intentions? When you change the query, you don't change the route which means you're navigating to the same page.

Comment: @Kyrony There is the main page of the catalog, on it the user selects a category, the category has a slug. The slug page contains all the elements of this category. The element itself is located on the id page. On page `[slug]/index` i got error if i run `prepare()` function. Code from this page. If I use this function in `middleware`, I will get the same error from nuxt, not from the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by using `router.replace` from `useRouter` instead of `NavigateTo`.  And an immediate call `watch(currentPage, () => { prepare()},{immediate:true})`

```js
const currentPage = useState<number>(() => 1)
if (query.page) currentPage.value=parseInt(query.page)
const prepare = async (): Promise<void> => {

    await router.replace({
        path: path,
        query: {
            page: currentPage.value,

        }
    });


    if (typeItem() && currentPage.value) {
        await loadMore(typeItem(), currentPage.value.toString())

    }
}

watch(currentPage, () => {
    prepare()

}, {immediate: true})
```